# Select2 despliega los options en el centro del modal

Tags: bootstrap, select2

En un formulario modal tengo una serie de select2 que se crean dinámicamente. El tema es que al desplegar los select que están señalados en la imagen en rojo, sus option se muestran en el centro de la pantalla (azul) y no ¨pegados¨ al select2 clickeado, si se selecciona uno de los options funciona bien, pero desde el punto de vista visual no está correcto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del formulario:

```
{% macro information_prototype(nacimiento, indice) %}
    <div class="nacimiento well well-sm text-small">       
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <strong>Fecha</strong>
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{form_widget(nacimiento.fechaNacimiento)}}
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Estado</strong>{{ form_widget(nacimiento.estado) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><strong>Sexo</strong>{{ form_widget(nacimiento.sexo) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Peso&nbsp;<span class="text-small">(g)</span></strong>{{ form_widget(nacimiento.pesoAlNacer) }}{{ form_errors(nacimiento.pesoAlNacer) }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <strong>Observaciones</strong>
                {{ form_widget(nacimiento.observaciones) }}
            </div>                                
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right">
                <a class="lnkAgregaNacimientoForm" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>&nbsp;
                <a class="lnkEliminarNacimientoForm" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well well-sm text-center">
            <b class="text-danger">
                <span class="icon icon-warning-sign"></span>&nbsp;Registre nacimientos a la embarazada si ocurren en esta Unidad.
            </b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <strong>Madre</strong>{{ form_widget(form.nombreMadre) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <strong>Tipo de Parto</strong>{{ form_widget(form.tipoPartoTuvo) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-bold">{{ form_widget(form.fallecida) }}</div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <strong>Fecha Fallece</strong>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{form_widget(form.fechafallecimiento)}}
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="contenedorNacimientos" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-prototype="{{ _self.information_prototype(form.nacimientos.vars.prototype)|escape('html') }}">
                {% for nacimiento in form.nacimientos %}
                    {{ _self.information_prototype(nacimiento, loop.index ) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var coleccionNacimientos = $('#contenedorNacimientos');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.mask-date, #registro_nacimientos_fechafallecimiento').inputmask('dd/mm/yyyy', {'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy'});

        coleccionNacimientos.data('index', coleccionNacimientos.length);
        $('#contenedorNacimientos').on('click', '.lnkAgregaNacimientoForm', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
            var prototype = coleccionNacimientos.data('prototype');
            // get the new index
            var index = coleccionNacimientos.data('index');
            // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on how many items we have
            var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
            // increase the index with one for the next item
            coleccionNacimientos.data('index', index + 1);
            // Display the new form fragment
            var resultado = $('#contenedorNacimientos').append(newForm);

            $('#modalCaptura').find('#registro_nacimientos_nacimientos_' + index + '_fechaNacimiento').val($('#modalCaptura').find('#registro_nacimientos_nacimientos_0_fechaNacimiento').val());
            $('#modalCaptura').find('#registro_nacimientos_nacimientos_' + index + '_estado, #registro_nacimientos_nacimientos_' + index + '_sexo').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#modalCaptura'),
                width: '100%',
                language: 'es'
            });
        });

        $('.selectt2, #registro_nacimientos_tipoPartoTuvo').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#modalCaptura'),
            width: '100%',
            language: 'es'
        });

        $('#contenedorNacimientos').on('click', '.lnkEliminarNacimientoForm', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var longitudColeccion = $('div.nacimiento').length;
            if (longitudColeccion > 1) {
                $(this).parents('div.nacimiento').remove();
            }
        });
        $('.iCheck').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue'
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución encontrada fue cambiar la propiedad `dropdownParent` de los select2 a un div que no sea el que se convierte en modal, pero que está en el `body` del modal. quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#modalCaptura').find('#registro_nacimientos_nacimientos_' + index + '_estado, #registro_nacimientos_nacimientos_' + index + '_sexo').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#contenedorForm'),
                width: '100%',
                language: 'es'
            });

$('.selectt2, #registro_nacimientos_tipoPartoTuvo').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#contenedorForm'),
            width: '100%',
            language: 'es'
        });
```